# How to identify if a Socket connection is made by Silverlight or from other types?

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets

I have a simple question: I need to identify if a socket connection is made from a Silverlight client ( so asks for a Policy file).
The only reason is that I want that only my Silverlight application can connect to the server I made. 
How can I do it in C#?

I could not find any discussion about that.

*Thanks,*

*Mattia*

Comment: It sound like it'd be easy for someone to impersonate your Silverlight client, if they wanted to. What security do you really need?

Comment: Send first message to server that `I'm from silver light` or some `Id` close the connections which doesn't know this `Id`

Comment: If you have control over the listener why don't you just sent a welcome message in a particular format only your SL client knows and then you can get the policy file

Comment: The reason is that I don't want to other people to see the communication between my Silverlight client and the server. Should I encrypt the communication? The idea of the welcome message with the ID is interesting, thanks!